# Keyboard shortcut for "Invert selection"

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, windows-10

Is there a dedicated windows keyboard shortcut for the "Invert Selection" command?

Comment: Not a keyboard shortcut, but you can hold Ctrl and select all files with your mouse.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Windows 8 + 10:**

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for Home tab in the ribbon, then <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>I</kbd> for Invert Selection.

[image]

**Windows 7:**

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to open up the Edit menu, then <kbd>I</kbd> for Invert Selection.

[image]

Comment: I want to know why MS had to make it a 2 character keyboard shortcut? There aren't THAT many options on the home ribbon tab that we can't have "I" or something. Alt-H-I ???

Comment: Seven years later, this is still inacceptable. Windows 10 gave us 1-click invert Selection, but Windows 11 took it away, then Windows 11 22H2 took it away *again*, and they *still* can't give us a keyboard shortcut for it!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method, which is what I use, is to add a registry entry for your shell right click menu. Therefore, when you select a file or folder(s), all you need to do is right click them and go to select > invert selection.

Add the following to a txt file, and then rename it to .reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Select]
"SubCommands"="Windows.invertselection"
"Position"="middle"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\Background\shell\Select]
"SubCommands"="Windows.invertselection"
"Position"="middle"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Select]
"SubCommands"="Windows.invertselection"
"Position"="middle"
```

This can expanded upon if you want, by adding more options to the subcommands, but that is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Using AutoHotKey (AHK v1) -

- For the [Windows 11 23H2](https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/windows-11/whats-new-with-file-explorer-on-windows-11-2023-update) Windows File Explorer -

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass")

^i::                      ; Ctrl + I
MouseMove 750, 150        ; see Note 1
Send {Click}              ; click on "see more" option
WinWait, PopupHost ahk_class Microsoft.UI.Content.PopupWindowSiteBridge ahk_exe explorer.exe,, 1 ; 1s
If ErrorLevel             ; if "see more" fails to open in 1 second
    Return                ; do nothing further
; Sleep 500                 ; alternative to WinWait ; see Note 2
Send {Up 3}               ; select "Invert selection" option
; Send {Enter}            ; see Note 3
Return                    ; The end

; Note 1: location of "see more" option on screen
; MouseMove - move the mouse cursor to x,y coordinates on 'Screen'
; use Window Spy to determine coordinates for your own screen(s)
; might want to change "CoordMode" if you have problems, visit 
; help page: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/CoordMode.htm

; Note 2: wait 500ms for window to respond to keys
; wait times (in milliseconds) don't work sometimes,
; try changing them to see what is sufficient for your PC spec/performance.
; Sometimes it doesn't work at all on the 1st try
; (ex: when a new explorer instance is first opened after login/restart)
; but works on subsequent attempts. *shrug* no idea why.

; Note 3: uncomment this line after test of previous steps
; or leave it as is if you prefer to do this step manually,
; especially if you notice inconsistent selection of options.

#If
```

- For ribbon UI enabled File Explorer (in older [Win 11](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/get-back-windows-10-ribbon-ui-windows-11/) and 7/8/8.1/10 systems) -

```
; Source: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=27564
#If WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass")

^i::                      ; Ctrl + I
ControlGet, hCtl, Hwnd,, SHELLDLL_DefView1, A
PostMessage, 0x111, 28706, 0,, % "ahk_id " hCtl ; edit, invert selection
return

#If
```