# windows - did ctrl+i invert selection in a folder?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-98, windows-2000, windows-95

In previous versions of Windows, was <kbd>Ctrl+i</kbd> ever a default shortcut key for inverting file selection in folders and on desktop?

I believe that it may have been present in Windows 2000 and earlier versions, but cannot remember for definite. I remember looking for software to achieve this functionality in Windows XP, and ever since, e.g. via AutoHotkey. A video of Windows 95 showed a menu item, 'invert selection', but no <kbd>Ctrl+i</kbd> next to it, although this is not proof either way. I ask here in case anyone has any older operating systems to hand.

In general, links and information regarding the history of Windows shortcut keys back to Windows 1.0 would be most welcome.

Comment: For Windows 7 to 10, check [this](http://superuser.com/questions/959945/keyboard-shortcut-for-invert-selection)

Comment: You write "A video of Windows 95 showed a menu item, 'invert selection', but no Ctrl+i next to it, although this is not proof either way." <-- it is proof that windows 95 didn't have it.  I've never noticed it in my usage of win98 or xp.  I didn't use win2000.. maybe you can find an image showing the edit menu in win 2000. I'd be surprised if the shortcut was there and they then removed it.  Apparently adobe photoshop has ctrl+I for "invert selection" http://digital-photography-school.com/28-more-exceptionally-useful-photoshop-shortcuts/